# It says memory leaks when i do CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);..........not able to get error

Tags: objective-c, memory

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGImageGetColorSpace(image);
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height,
                                             CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(image),
                                             CGImageGetBytesPerRow(image),
                                             colorspace,
                                             CGImageGetAlphaInfo(image));
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
if(context == NULL)
    return nil;
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), image);
CGImageRef imgRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
CGContextRelease(context);
```

This is my full code....

Answer (score 0):

CGBitmapContextCreate returns an object through the COPY operation. You need to release it too. 
you must call CGContextRelease on context.